# What is the difference between ClickOnce (for WinForms) and Direct Web Install (for UWP)

Tags: .net, winforms, uwp, clickonce, windows-10-universal

Windows 10.0.16299 (Fall Anniversary) introduced the ability to install Universal Windows applications directly from a web site. This is good news for those of us in Enterprise environments where we have no internal Windows App Store, or for developers who may want to deploy their applications privately, outside of the Microsoft store environment.

Installing and running from a web site sounds much like something I'm more familiar with: ClickOnce deployments. ClickOnce had a very simple installation experience, where a WinForms executable could install locally, including placing a link in the start menu, directly from a web page. Better yet, ClickOnce would keep programs up to date by checking for a new version every time the application starts.

Is Direct Web Install technology for UWP apps essentially the same? Does Direct Web Install keep apps up to date via the web? What is the difference?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2017/09/27/automated-app-updates-with-appinstaller-file/ discusses the auto-update system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential difference here is still the fact that ClickOnce deployment is compatible with classic desktop apps and could not be used for UWP, whereas the Direct Web install works with UWP packaged apps only.

The ClickOnce deployment is a bit more customizable, because it enabled the developer to customize the auto-update behavior and was capable of updating the app before launch.

In contrast Direct Web install still supports auto-update and can check for the updates from the source endpoint, but the new version is check in lieu with user using the app, so it will be installed only after she closes the app. Also note that updates are checked only once per 24 hours, so if the user installs the app, launches it, then you push an update and the user uses the app once again the same day, the new version will not be checked yet. You should however be able to use the [StorePackageUpdate APIs](http://StorePackageUpdateStatus) to force check for updates and inform the user about pending downloads.